# Center image into figure

Tags: html, css

I have a question that is more than spoken, but I can't find a solution.

I have this HTML:

```
 <section class="section" id="section-2">

        <div class="wrapper" id="wrapper">

            <div class="slider-container" id="slider-container">

                <figure class="panel-image">
                    <img src="imgs/projects/3d-particles-image.png">
                </figure>

                <figure class="panel-image">
                    <img src="imgs/projects/3d-particles-image.png">
                </figure>

            </div>

        </div>

    </section>
```

And this CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slider-container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.panel-image {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100%;
}

.panel-image > img { ????????? }
```

I need center the img into figure, but the position of "panel-image" need to be absolute.
Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, it [appears to be centered horizontally](http://jsfiddle.net/franciscop/f9nvLz9n/). What is the problem? Vertically? Other?

Comment: Yes, the problem is centered vertically

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this works in modern browsers:

```
.panel-image > img { 
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;

-webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
-moz-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
-ms-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
-o-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

There are more elaborate tricks for older browsers.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks @ralph.m! Works fine!!

I find another solution:

```
.panel-image {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
}

.panel-image > img {
    margin: auto;
}
```